# How to reset the Windows 10 video codecs?

Tags: windows-10, video-codecs

I am using Windows 10 (x64). I have installed it from the latest ISO available in April - IIRC it was a 2022-11 build.

Three days ago I found the computer stopped (I leave it always in suspended mode) and since then the videos won't play, except AVI files. I tried with Windows Media Player, Media Player Classic and VLC Player. They all do the same: they play the video but the image is blank (black window).

I had to install VirtualDub2, mpv and SMPlayer and it works in all of them since they use ffmpeg and not the Windows codecs, I guess.

I thought VLC has it's own codecs though! Or it's not about codecs but about the output?

I do not have internet but I can use my mobile phone as a hotspot. How can I make the videos play again from all players?

Comment: Update the video driver

Comment: VLC does have its own codecs.

Comment: Does it happen with multiple video formats? If you suspect a bad codec, you could install a codec pack such as [K-Lite](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) (although even if this helped it wouldn't explain why VLC has this problem).